# Button taking too much space

Tags: android, layout

I still dont really get it how many space layouts take.

I have the following xml.
The inner `LinearLayout's` for the bottom space height is set to `wrap_content`, so it should take the height of the maximum height in there. Which is `52dp`. And there is the `ImageButton` which is set to `wrap_content`, so the button should be centered vertically on the right side, since its an `24dp` image (in xhdpi it has 32x32 pixels). So why is it stretched over the full height like displayed here?:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <de.ph1b.audiobook.utils.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editBook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either `@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_24dp` is larger than you think or `borderlessButtonStyle` has a larger background.

Please check the size. I have replicated the behavior and the `ImageButton` is set to `wrap_content` and is centered.

Comment: Its  the borderlessButtonStyle.

Answer (score 0):

change your image button code

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/editBook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_24dp" />
```